# Difference between defining a value in color and drawable tag?

Tags: android, colors, drawable

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="red">#7f00</drawable>
....
    <color name="solid_red">#f00</color>
.....
</resources>
```

This is some part of the colors.xml from android samples directory.

Now my question is that,  what is the difference between defining a color in `<drawable>` tag and `<color>` tag ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically nothing.  They both create a resource that is a "color" value holding a 32 bit color.  One is just a drawable subtype, one is a color subtype.  When you retrieve a Drawable from resources, if the resource is actually a color constant it knows how to create a Drawable object for that.